# How to copy a CVPixelBuffer in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, avfoundation, porting, cvpixelbuffer

I'm trying to port some ObjC-Code to Swift. The code is part of the Flutter [Camera-Plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m) (line 265). The plugin allows a live preview of the camera.

As a Swift programmer I have no idea what is happening here. What does `OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier()` do and how can this code be transferred to Swift?

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef)copyPixelBuffer {
  CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = _latestPixelBuffer;
  while (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(pixelBuffer, nil, (void **)&_latestPixelBuffer)) {
    pixelBuffer = _latestPixelBuffer;
  }
  return pixelBuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

OSAtomic is used when there are multiple threads and when you need to ensure that between the time you assign and check a variable, things haven't changed. Let me give you a detailed explanation of why it was required here but in summary you don't need to worry about this in Swift as the Swift Runtime will take care of this particular scenario.

**Detailed Explanation:** There are two active threads (DispatchQueues), one that captures CVPixelBuffer `captureOutput:` and the other one that calls `copyPixelBuffer:` to pass on the CVPixelBuffer to flutter.

When `captureOutput:` is called, the current frame is extracted using `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer`, which requires the caller to call CFRetain to keep the buffer in memory and when the buffer is no longer required, CFRelease is to be called to release the memory. Luckily, Flutter automatically calls CFRelease on the passed on pixelBuffer, so we just have to call CFRetain and don't have to worry about releasing the buffer as flutter will do that for us. However, if a new frame is acquired before the old one is handed over to Flutter, we would have to call CFRelease on the old one, as it would never be given to flutter.

So how do we know if the buffer has been handed over to Flutter? Well, whenever the buffer is handed over to flutter, we can set `_latestPixelBuffer = nil;` and whenever a new buffer is produced we can check `if _latestPixelBuffer != nil` we can call CFRelease on it. So without OSAtomic, the function would (wrongly) look like:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output
    didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
           fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

    CVPixelBufferRef newBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CFRetain(newBuffer);

    // WRONG IMPLEMENTATION FOLLOWS

    CVPixelBufferRef old = _latestPixelBuffer;
    // Reference Point 1
    _latestPixelBuffer = newBuffer;

    if (old != nil) {
      CFRelease(old);
    }

- (CVPixelBufferRef)copyPixelBuffer {
  CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = _latestPixelBuffer;

  // WRONG IMPLEMENTATION
  _latestPixelBuffer = nil;

  return pixelBuffer;
}
```

Since, it is multithreaded (in fact flutter uses GPU thread), there can be a scenario that by the time we reach `// Reference Point 1`, where we have already copied the old frame's reference in `old` and are about to save the new frame in `_latestPixelBuffer` but **before we can** execute the line, flutter's thread calls copyPixelBuffer. So we hand over the old frame to Flutter and now it would be flutter's responsibility to call CFRelease on it. However, our thread, would still see _old still referring to the old frame (as that line was executed before flutter had called) and hence we would accidentally call CFRelease on it.

So what we need is a guarantee that inside `captureOutput:` when we assign `_latestPixelBuffer = newBuffer`, there is no way flutter's thread can get the old buffer OR if it does, then we want our `old` to refer to nil as well so that we don't call CFRelease on it. This is where `OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier` comes in handy.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output
    didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
           fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

    CVPixelBufferRef newBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CFRetain(newBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferRef old = _latestPixelBuffer;
    while (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(old, newBuffer, (void **)&_latestPixelBuffer)) {
      old = _latestPixelBuffer;
    }
    if (old != nil) {
      CFRelease(old);
    }
```

It will check if `_latestPixelBuffer` == `old`, only then it will assign `_latestPixelBuffer = newBuffer`. If during this time flutter's thread has been called, `_latestPixelBuffer` would have been set to `nil` inside `copyPixelBuffer:` and OSAtomic will fail since `_latestPixelBuffer != old` anymore. This is where the body of the while loop comes into play and here we set `old = _latestPixelBuffer;` again but this time `old` will get the new value set by flutter's thread. Now, when OSAtomic will be called, it will set `_latestPixelBuffer = newBuffer`.

For this to work, **all threads** that change the value of `_latestPixelBuffer`  need to use `OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier`. That is the reason `copyPixelBuffer:` also uses this function:

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef)copyPixelBuffer {
  CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = _latestPixelBuffer;
  while (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(pixelBuffer, nil, (void **)&_latestPixelBuffer)) {
    pixelBuffer = _latestPixelBuffer;
  }

  return pixelBuffer;
}
```

In Swift, we don't call CFRetain on the return value of `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer` as the Swift Runtime does that for us. Since, the runtime calls CFRetain for us, it is the runtime's responsibility to call CFRelease on it as well. However, in `copyPixelBuffer`, we will need to return `Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>.passRetained(latestPixelBuffer!)` so that Flutter can call CFRelease on it.

Comment: That was an interesting read, but I'm still unclear on how to move forward implementing this method in Swift. Any additional help would be appreciated.

Comment: Very good explanation of how things work in camera plugin; cheers! I have a doubt and I think your opinion could be golden, could you please check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62795428/whats-the-best-way-to-launch-a-periodic-task-in-ios-camera-to-use-frames-data ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your explanation was great. But as @LukePighetti mentions, it would be helpful if you could add a working definition for the copyPixelBuffer property in Swift.

Comment: +1 for the good explanation... For me not fully understanding is as a result of not fully grounded in swift or objective C but i got the idea and that fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

in captureOutput delegate method

```
let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
```

and then

```
public func copyPixelBuffer() -> Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>? {
    if(pixelBuffer == nil){
        return nil
    }
    return  Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>.passRetained(pixelBuffer)
}
```