# What's the best way to launch a periodic task in iOS camera to use frames data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter, ios-camera, periodic-task

I am building a cross-platform tool that uses frames from camera to do some work on them. I'm starting from [this code-base](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m), which is the camera Flutter plugin. My goal is to have a periodic task (running every 200ms) that does some work in parallel (so it does not interfere with frame-rate). For this, my goal is to store every frame that comes from camera and, when the task is triggered, last stored frame is used for some calculations.

Below, I'll show what I've done, but I think this is not the right way to do it and that it is not truly running on a separate thread.

1. Save the CVPixelBuffer frame as property of [FLTCam](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/3b931d0a9c10e6a833cff1dffcd8e6a947a43936/packages/camera/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m#L158)

```
    @property(readwrite, atomic) CVPixelBufferRef volatile lastFramePixelBuffer;
```

2. Save lastFramePixelBuffer in [captureOutput](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/3b931d0a9c10e6a833cff1dffcd8e6a947a43936/packages/camera/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m#L345), after [(l350) CFRetain(newBuffer);](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/3b931d0a9c10e6a833cff1dffcd8e6a947a43936/packages/camera/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m#L350)

```
    _lastFramePixelBuffer = newBuffer;
```

3. Launch periodic task in [camera start](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/3b931d0a9c10e6a833cff1dffcd8e6a947a43936/packages/camera/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m#L267)

```
  [self startTimedTask]; //in [camera start]
```

```
- (void)startTimedTask  //start periodic task in 5 seconds
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(startTimedTaskRepeat) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    });
}

- (void)startTimedTaskRepeat  // trigger periodic task every 0.2secs
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(performBackgroundTask) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    });
}

- (void)performBackgroundTask 
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        //Do background work
        [self doBackgroundWork];
    });
}

- (void)doBackgroundWork{  // the task, which takes about 100ms
    CVPixelBufferRef frame = _pixelBufferToInfere;
    CFRetain(frame);
    NSLog(@"Image size is: H = %zd", CVPixelBufferGetHeight(frame));NSLog(@"Image size is: W = %zd", CVPixelBufferGetWidth(frame));
    [self calculate:frame]; 
    CFRelease(frame);    
}
```

I want to know the best way to achieve this parallel computing and the most recent frame "caching" in a reliable and safe way, right now the interval between executions of the task seems inconsistent and fps seem to get a little lower.

**UPDATE**

I'm currently using (instead of function `startTimedTask`) the function below

```
- (void)startTimedTaskRepeat2
{
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    self->timerSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, backgroundQueue);
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timerSource, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0), 0.2*NSEC_PER_SEC, 0*NSEC_PER_SEC); 
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timerSource, ^{
        [self infereFrame];
    });
    dispatch_resume(timerSource);
}
```

Also, I should point out that it is in fact more important for me to achieve full parallel and efficient computing, even if I have to sacrifice a couple milliseconds in periodic precision

Comment: Do note that in your question you say "every .2 *or so*" but later you assert you want high precision. (Note that you goal is impossible anyway.)

Comment: I've updated the question for coherency reasons, focusing more on the point I am trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, dispatch_source_set_timer from your edit is for sure more precise than NSTimer. Possibly you would get even better precision if you launched it with a lower delay for example 10 ms instead of 200 ms and inside it's handler use current timestamp from [NSDate new] to check if 200ms passed from last processing and now is the time to fire this processing again. As you launch this timer on a backgroundQueue you already run it in parallel so it seems that you already have what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: it's inconceivable you can get times anything like that accurate, with iOS / the camera system.  it's just not even in the ballpark.

Comment: I quite agree with @Fattie due to the time that it might take to process something. You can't define the time that a task has to load. If you set a timer (200ms), the task might or might not have been processed when time's up. The process takes the time that wants. However, I do encourage you to test, and see if the times that you want are achievable. If there are the desired results under the time threshold, great.

Answer (score 1):

No need for timers for this, since you need a video frame to do your work in the first place, use the reception of the frame as the trigger for your task.
At camera startup:

```
NSTimeInterval lastProcessingTime = CurrentMediaTime()
```

in captureOutput callback:

```
NSTimeInterval now = CurrentMediaTime();
if (now-lastProcessingTime > 0.2) {
    lastProcessingTime = now;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
       // Do your background work
    });
}
```

The 0.2 corresponds to 200ms of course. It should be reasonably precise since the frame rate is fairly regular.
Make sure your background processing takes less than 200 ms though, otherwise your app will blow up sooner or later.

Answer (score -1):

OP,

> "I need to be very precise ..."

Unfortunately, completely forget it.

There's no way to do "very precise" timing with iPhones (and indeed, almost all common commercial OS).

Your project is misconceived, I'm sorry to say.

In particular, when you're pulling from the *camera*, it's particularly hopeless, timing is very erratic.

(This is a huge misconception with - say - game engines.  Folks will try to set a timer "precisely" to some value.  Of course, game engines are *frame based* - it simply runs the item in whatever frame happens to have passed the timer amount. And frame timings are completely erratic.)