# Flutter(Objective-C) Camera: processing and showing processed live-preview cvPixelBuffer doesn't work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter, dart, cvpixelbuffer

Im working on extending existing flutter cameraPlugin for IOS..
What do I basically need:

- **catch** live-preview frame.
- **process** it (in my case apply some openCV logic), return **UIImage**
- **convert** it into the **CvPixelBuffer** and return it to the flutter.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54851275/12670782) I found great explanation how to does Flutter communicate with Objective-C camera.

Step 1: inside **captureOutput** I caught a frame, applied some interaction logic, which returns **edited** **UIImage**, converted to the CvPixelBuffer, but unfortunately it doesn't work.
Returned image could be nil, in such case I should return default preview frame (which works fine).

```
UIImage* image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer];
InteractingResultContainer* resultContainer = [_cameraPreviewInteractor operateOnImageFrame: image];
  if(resultContainer.image != nil) {
      CVPixelBufferRef editedBuffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage: resultContainer.image.CGImage];
      CFRetain(editedBuffer);
      CVPixelBufferRef old = _latestPixelBuffer;
      while (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(old, editedBuffer, (void **)&_latestPixelBuffer)) {
          old = _latestPixelBuffer;
      }
      if (old != nil) {
          CFRelease(old);
      }
  }
  else {
      CVPixelBufferRef newBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
      CFRetain(newBuffer);
      CVPixelBufferRef old = _latestPixelBuffer;
      while (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(old, newBuffer, (void **)&_latestPixelBuffer)) {
          old = _latestPixelBuffer;
      }
      if (old != nil) {
          CFRelease(old);
      }
      
  }
  
  if (_onFrameAvailable) {
      _onFrameAvailable();
  }
```

However, debug breakpoints telling that they're returning right (edited, with red circle drawn) cvPixelBuffers to the Flutter:
[image]

[Origin Flutter's Camera Plugin Source](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/camera/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m)
Working w/ **captureOutput** method, (line **592**)

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I've found the issue of the texture interoperability you are likely having.  Based on this answer in an issue, you need to create the CVPixelBuffer with interop with Metal and OpenGL in order to use the FlutterTexture mechanism.  If you don't, it looks like the CVPixelBuffer is unable to be converted to a MetalTexture (or OpenGL texture depending on platform) https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59410#issuecomment-644350728

Comment: @SeanLangley did you manage to figure this out? Where should we use this jist mentioned in the git issue?